# Fatal error on query command

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP portion of code:

```
$indice_man = $html->find('div.man', 0);


            foreach($indice_man->find('div.block_results') as $e_trial_man) {

                foreach($e_trial_man->find('tr.line_results') as $result_man) {

                       $div_medal_man = $result_man->getElementByTagName('div');
                       $medal_man = explode(' ',$div_medal_man->getAttribute('class'));

                        $Trial = trim($e_trial_man->childNodes(0)->plaintext);
                        $Medal = $medal_man[1];
                        $Sex = male;
                        $Name = trim($result_man->find('td.name',0)->plaintext);
                        $Country = trim($result_man->find('td.country',0)->plaintext);

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO OlympicMedal (Olimpiade, Sport, Disciplina, Medaglia, Categoria, Atleta, Nazione) VALUES ('$Game', '$Sport', '$Trial','$Medal', '$Sex', '$Name','$Country')";

                   }

                }
```

I get the error:

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non object [...]**

but if I put an **`echo $Medal`** command before the insert sql, it prints correctly so I don't think getAttribute is the issue.
I think is about the query at this point, where am I wrong?

Fabio

Comment: print $medal_man value and check or check query once

Comment: check `$div_medal_man`, whether it has `getAttribute` function or not

Answer (score 0):

You need the check `$div_medal_man` before using `$div_medal_man->getAttribute('class')`. Cause you need know is `$div_medal_man` really has a  `getAttribute` function.

Answer (score 0):

check $div_medal_man. It may be a collection of objects or null.
http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php#85182

Answer (score 0):

You are in foreach loop. So you printed only for first record. You get  `$Medal` for first record correctly.

But one of your record has no `getAttribute` function in `$div_medal_man` object. So you need to check below condition.

Use [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

```
if(method_exists($div_medal_man, 'getAttribute')){
    $medal_man =  explode(' ',$div_medal_man->getAttribute('class'));              
 }else{
     $medal_man = '';   
 }

 $Medal = isset($medal_man) ? $medal_man[1] : 'no_value';
```

Hope it will work for you :)